VSCode Terminal.runSelectedText SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement
I updated my Windows version from Windows 10 to Windows 11. I used to run multiple lines of code in the VSCode terminal at the same time using shortcuts thanks to the option Terminal.runSelectedText. It works perfectly well in Windows 10 and also for Linux (connecting via ssh), but for some reason now I am getting errors of the form
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

when I run several lines of code in Windows 11 when I am connected via ssh to Linux machine. This happens with pretty basic statements like the following
import os
import sys

Please, keep in mind that I am accustomed to run code in Python, but I never had this problem with Windows 10 when I am connecting via ssh to a linux machine. However, the problem started appear since I updated my Windows version to Windows 11.
Is there a way to run multiple lines of code again using the same shortcut when I am using Windows 11 and I am connected to a Linux Machine? Certainly I can run the code line by line using the same shorcut but this is not the point since it would be extremely inefficient.

How are you triggering this?

Ensure that this setting "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": true has been added to your USER settings.json. At the same time, you could create a code block in a Python script and run it as a whole. This avoids issues with line endings and terminal interpretation.
